# GCP: Cloud Functions: Does the CF reinstall the requirements.txt whenever it is triggered?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gitlab

We currently have many Cloud Functions deployed. They use git+ssh in their requirements.txt to grab code from other projects.

We want to switch our git address.

Do we need to update the cloud function beforehand or is the requirements.txt only important when the cloud functions was deployed?

For the next deployment we would update all requirements.txt files. But out of some reasons we can't do this right now and we would have to delay the git address project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do we need to update the cloud function beforehand or is the requirements.txt only important when the cloud functions was deployed?

It's only used at the time of deployment in order to build a docker container that has everything needed to run the function.  Once that container is built and deployed, no dependencies will be missing at runtime.

If you want to make changes to the dependencies, while the function is deployed, that's fine - the function will just keep using the ones that were baked into its container.

Comment: You should be able to mark the answer as correct by using the checkmark to the left.